# phonegap app dose not extended to take the device size

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

Im finished from developing phonegap application , but I have a problem with layout , i use css file to make it , my problem is the application dose not take the device screen size , i want it to be flexible and app extend to take the suitable size.
any help will be greatly appreciated.
Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the CSS you use is forcing a width or height somewhere. Instead of using a specific pixel size for elements, try using percents (at least for the widths). You may also want learn about responsive web design to help design effective UIs for mobile devices. A simple Google search should get you going on learning that.

Answer (score 0):

With PhoneGap you definitely can find the device screen size:

```
var widthScreen = window.innerWidth;
var heightScreen = window.innerHeight;
```

According to the sizes you get you can safely assume what kind of device you are working with and have a critical information when designing interface.

Answer (score 0):

use percent, but in some specific ways, when you need something in pixels you can use different css style files. For exapmle 
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-device-width : 240px) 
and (max-device-width : 320px) " href="css/small.css" />`

Answer (score 0):

You can use Css3 media-query for solve your problem or

or you can use

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1">
```

I hope Solve :D